# Why is my linked list not printing? And is it even creating list?

Tags: java, methods, system.out

I'm new to programming and this is my first post here at stackoverflow. Below is code I'm working on trying to create a linked list with a for loop, and then simply printing out the list. I'm also completing this using the basic fundamental methods of linked list(not using built in functions). I'm unsure why it's not printing. I've watched several videos, searched on stackoverflow, and googled the topic, yet to no avail..

```
package basiclinkedlist;
import java.util.*;

public class BasicLinkedList {

    public class node{
        public int data;
        public node next;
    }


    public node front;
    public void init(){
        front = null;
    }

    public node makeNode(int num){
        node newNode;
        newNode = new node();
        newNode.data = num;
        newNode.next = null;
        return newNode;
    }

    public node findTail(node front){
        node current;
        current = front;
        while(current.next != null){
            current = current.next;
        }
        return current;
    }

    public void makeList(int length){
        int j;
        node tail;
        front = makeNode(0);
        tail = front;
        for(j=1;j<length;j++){
            tail.next = makeNode(j);
            tail = tail.next;
        }

    }

    public void showList(){
        node current;
        current = front;
        while(current != null){
            System.out.println(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        BasicLinkedList obj = new BasicLinkedList();
        BasicLinkedList obj1 = new BasicLinkedList();
        BasicLinkedList obj2 = new BasicLinkedList();
        obj.init();
        obj1.makeList(9);
        obj2.showList();

    }


}
```

Comment: Do you have a `node` as a field in your `node` class?! Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you're creating data on `obj1` but you're attempting to display data on `obj2` which is still empty.